# How can I represent a given memory layout, rather than mathematical value, in C?

Tags: c, endianness

Ugh, endianness. The problem is the memory layout of say, `0x65736c6166` will be different on different endians. This is because the number is being defined by value. The `66` on the end of my constant will go in the first byte on little endian systems, and on the last byte on big endian systems, yet the number is the same. How can I define number variables by **memory layout** rather than by value, so on different endians, their memory layout will stay the same, but their value will be completely different? And it needs to be considered compile-time constant.

Comment: Generally you don't.  Why exactly do you think you need to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve that you think this will answer?

Comment: @dbush I need to control the memory layout of a variable. I am using binary operations were the memory layout of the value is what matters, not the mathematical evaluation of the value.

Comment: "And it needs to be considered compile-time constant." --> Why.  Post its use.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Comparing [memory representations of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006673/whats-the-proper-way-to-copy-a-char-array-of-a-given-size-to-an-integer-in-c) against values in switch cases.

Comment: Hmmm, [`Tfalse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63005000/2410359) is a compile-time constant

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier if you would actually post the code and explain how do you want to use that value.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica But is it endian-independant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I define number variables by memory layout rather than by value, so on different endians, their memory layout will stay the same, but their value will be completely different?

Well, there are only two endianess to handle. You could write a macro function that would convert host byte order to the endianess you want and just use such macro when using the constant.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// Copied from glibc bits/byteswap.h
#define bswap_constant_64(x) \
  ((((x) & 0xff00000000000000ull) >> 56)    \
   | (((x) & 0x00ff000000000000ull) >> 40)  \
   | (((x) & 0x0000ff0000000000ull) >> 24)  \
   | (((x) & 0x000000ff00000000ull) >> 8)   \
   | (((x) & 0x00000000ff000000ull) << 8)   \
   | (((x) & 0x0000000000ff0000ull) << 24)  \
   | (((x) & 0x000000000000ff00ull) << 40)  \
   | (((x) & 0x00000000000000ffull) << 56))

// __BYTE_ORDER__ and __ORDER_BYTE_ORDER__ are macros defined by gcc
// use different check when compiling with a compiler that doesnt define them
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define HTOLE64(x)  (x)
#else
#define HTOLE64(x)  bswap_constant_64(x)
#endif

// yes a constant expression
static unsigned long long mynumber = HTOLE64(0x65736c6166ull);

int main() {
    char bytes[sizeof(mynumber)];
    memcpy(bytes, &mynumber, sizeof(mynumber));
    // works on any endianess
    assert(bytes[0] == 0x66);
    assert(bytes[1] == 0x61);
}
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/65WGrW).

Comment: That works, but is there a simpler and more portable way to do that?

Comment: I suspect if there would be, there also would be an answer here with such way. Using [endian.h](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/endian.h.html) is the way such problems got solved in C - just here `HTOLE64` is a compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not an integer constant expression, you can define for example:

```
#define X ((union { unsigned char r[8]; uint64_t v; }){ 0x65, 0x73, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x66 }.v)
```

and `X` now expands to an expression of type `uint64_t` defined in terms of its representation not its value.

Comment: Is that considered compile-time constant?

Comment: @user13783520: Depends on what you mean by that.

Comment: *6.6 Constant expressions ¶8* defines an arithmetic constant expression in a way that excludes expressions containing compound literals, so this means it's not valid for use in initializers of objects with static storage duration unless the implementation allows them as an extension. But if you just care whether it will be evaluated at compile time in contexts where it's already legal (i.e. if you just care about performance), for all practical purposes the answer is yes.

Comment: It needs to be compile-time constant like what's accepted as a static initializer switch case etc.

Comment: What is "ice" that GitHub should stop helping?